# Xamarin Forms Shared HttpClient Connection Limits

Tags: xamarin.forms, httprequest, httpclient

I am using a shared HttpClient instance in our xamarin forms and some parts of our application shoot off a lot of HttpRequestMessage async at the same time. I noticed in a situation where we have 47 separate web calls which are shot at exactly the same time it will only process approx 20 at a time and once they are complete it will process the next 20 and so on.

How do we go about setting it so we can remove the limit and all httpClient HttpRequestMessage at the same time?

Comment: Can you please have a try to set the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections?redirectedfrom=MSDN)? Here is an code example:[example](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/KnownIssues/534719-Networking.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit%20default%20behavior%20changed.md)

Comment: Have changed those settings with no difference. Am testing on UWP

Comment: Well, the document said the limit for HTTP connections per endpoint is controlled by the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit property. You can open a free [ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6) for more help.